# Can React re-render only a portion of component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Thinking efficiency-wise, is it possible to re-render only a portion of a component's `render` method?

I'm not talking about `shouldComponentUpdate`, which asks if the whole component should re-render.

Let's say I have:

```
class Cmponent extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
        <div className="div1"></div>
        <div className="div2"></div>
        <div className="div3"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Assume I want to dynamically display `.div3`. For example using a state flag `showDiv3` with a toggle, e.g:

```
class Cmponent extends React.Component{

    //assume a code that initializes showDiv3 and provides a toggle function

    render(){
        return(
        <div className="div1"></div>
        <div className="div2"></div>
        {this.state.showDiv3 ? (<div className="div3"></div>) : null}
        );
    }
}
```

Is it possible in React to tell the component it should only re-render `div3` when I toggle it? Or it'll always re-render the whole component via a state change?

I assume that on small components (such as this) it won't matter much, but on bigger ones it might make a big impact on performance (right?).

Comment: `setState` will call the `render` method again.

Comment: Yes, by memoizing all divs only the 3rd one will render. Or if they didn't change, they won't render anyway

Comment: under the hood, only div 3 will be rerendered. Or you can split div3 to own component and pass prop down and memorize component

Comment: @cuongdevjs I thought so, but I figured it didn't when I saw the whole component being updated when I toggled "Highlight updates when components render" in React Devtools.

Comment: There are two *render*s in React: first is when `render()` function is called and it produces React elements tree. Then this tree is compared to the previous elements tree in the process called reconciliation and the list of patches (updates to the DOM to make it reflect the new elements tree) is generated. Then this list of patches is applied to the DOM. That's the second *render*. If the new React elements tree is the same as the previous one, the list of patches will be empty, so DOM won't be changed, that is there won't be anything rendered to the DOM.

Comment: Since React elements tree is just a tree of plain JS objects, rendering the tree and comparing it is quite fast, so most of the time you don't have to worry about it. However, in this regard React is quite archaic because frameworks like Vue3 or Svelte can figure out what parts are static and what parts are dynamic and don't waste the time comparing things that obviously never change like your fist two `div`s.

Comment: In React, there are ways to tell React that it shouldn't reconcile some parts because they're the same. First is passing it the exact same (referentially identical) React element tree. The second one is to use `React.memo` or `shouldComponentUpdate` (but you should switch from `class` components to `function` components if you can). This has downside because React still needs to do some work (compare props) so when used recklessly it can actually slow down the app.

Comment: @marzelin thank you! It fits well with Dennis' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="div1"></div>
        <div className="div2"></div>
        {this.state.showDiv3 ? <div className="div3"></div> : null}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

The `Component` itself will re-render (the `render` function will be called) because of `setState` call.

For the components it renders, by default (props shallow comparison) only `div3` will re-render (remount), see [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

If you switch the divs with custom components, you can memoize them by having a custom props comparison function (check `React.memo`/`React.PureComponent`/`shouldComponentUpdate`).

Comment: I see. I'll read on reconciliation. Please look at my comment to cuongdevjs in the question; does that mean that the component updates without rendering anything but the actually changed part? Is it possible to see what was *rendered* instead of what was *updated* in react devtools?

Comment: You have a fire graph in dev tools that tells which elements rerendered, aside from it you can just log something in render function i.e make pure component instead of div1,2 and see if it rerenders.